# Upstart vs Systemd Performance

Tags: performance, upstart, systemd

Has anyone measured difference in performance between these 2 systems on Ubuntu?

Systemd is coming, and it has it's merits, but I fear Upstart will be tough to beat on Ubuntu, since it had years of tuning. Please note that it's only **performance on (*)ubuntu** that I'm asking about.

Comment: What do you mean by performance? Boot time?

Comment: Yes. Boot time should be affected the most, and easiest to measure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

boot performance under systemd can be measured with the 
    `systemd-analyze plot`
tool. Realize that Ubuntu running systemd is very similar to Debian, which is very similar to every other GNU/Linux distro.

Comment: I find that shut-down times are much shorter than with upstart.